# How to force the form focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus

How can I force the focus of an form? `.Focus()` is not working for me.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   var form = new loginForm();
    if (Application.OpenForms[form.Name] == null) {
           form.Show();
    } else {
         form.Focus();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it should be

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   var form = new loginForm();
    if (Application.OpenForms[form.Name] == null) {
           form.Show();
    } else {
         Application.OpenForms[form.Name].Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: not worked for me. if the form is minimized and I click in button1 the forme is not activated (placed in focus).

Comment: sorry, did you see the edit? which one did you try? Select() or Focus() ?

Comment: works fine now. Thanks! but by curiosity, why doing referencing to `form` variable does not works?

Comment: because it is a different instance, and not the one that is minimized at the moment. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: You were creating a new form and trying to focus it, instead of trying to focus the existing one

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
this.BringToFront();
this.Activate();
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to show the form first - use the [`Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) method:

```
var form = new loginForm();
form.Show();
```

**Edit:** (updated question)

For an existing form calling [`Activate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) might be more appropriate, this also brings the form to the front:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   var form = new loginForm();
    if (Application.OpenForms[form.Name] == null) 
    {
           form.Show();
    } 
    else 
    {
        Application.OpenForms[form.Name].Activate();
    }
}
```

If the form is minimized you need to subscribe to the `Activated` event to change your window state to `FormWindowState.Normal`:

```
private void loginForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me, but this does:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    Focus();
}
```

None of the focusing methods worked if called before this event. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

On start of the form we add
this.BringToFront();
this.Activate();