# How to set the focus on a form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to set the focus on a popup form I have created when the mouse hover it,
I checked MSDN and they said to use the *SetFocuse* method but it does not work.

I tried this:

```
private void POPUPmainmanue_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        POPUPmainmanue.SetFocus();
    }
```

Comment: I believe it already has to have focus for the mouse hover event to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force the form focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461005/how-to-force-the-form-focus)

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but I could find no `SetFocus()` method for a `Form` on MSDN.

However, using the `Activate()` methods works well enough.

```
private void POPUPmainmanue_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    POPUPmainmanue.Activate();
}
```

Also, always make sure you do not forget to set the EventHandler:

```
POPUPmainmanue.MouseHover += POPUPmainmanue_MouseHover;
```

You also did not mention whether you are using WinForms or WPF, although I think it's the former as you say 'form'. Again, what exactly is `POPUPmainmanue`? A form? I don't think so. A form does not have a `SetFocus()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's easy to implement, cause it's not very clear the question:
It's possible to set focus on textbox when the mouse hovers the form, and another more clear possiblity to set focus on a form when a form opens.

```
        this.BringToFront();
        this.Activate();
```