# How to Focus to another form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program which opens two forms
and I want when I `click` on `Form1`
then `Focus` on `Form2`.

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Focus();
}
```

But this doesn't work, what's wrong in my code?

**EDIT:**
**I found  already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461005/how-to-force-the-form-focus/8461035#8461035)** by **@moguzalp** at the comments

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461035/492258)

Comment: don't create new instance it will work

Comment: Thanks its Working @moguzalp
can you post this as answer?

Comment: @KiraSama Answer already given on relevant Q&A. You could upvote it if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have a form opened, try *finding* it:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Do we have any Form2 instances opened?
Form2 frm2 = Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<Form2>()
  .LastOrDefault(); // <- If we have many Form2 instances, let's take the last one 

// ...No. We have to create and show Form2 instance
if (null == frm2) {
  frm2 = new Form2();
  frm2.Show(); 
}
else { // ...Yes. We have to activate it (i.e. bring to front, restore if minimized, focus)
  frm2.Activate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all that Form2 is never visible.

```
    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    frm2.Focus();
}
```

If that Form is visible though with your code, that means you need to get same reference and call `Focus()` against it.

---

EDIT:

---

Then you need to have a reference to that Form. 
At some point you created that Form and assigned it to a vairable/field or anything like that.

You need to call `Focus` or `Activate` against it.

Example:

Inside `Form1` when you create a `Form2` instance:

```
public class Form1 : Form 
{
   private Form _frm2;


   //That code you probably have somewhere. You need to make sure that this Form instance is accessible inside the handler to use it.
   public void Stuff() {
     _frm2 = new Form2();
     _frm2.Show();
   }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frm2.Focus(); //or _frm2.Activate();
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry but i said that i'am already showed Form2
and i want to Just focus on it when i click at Form1

Comment: your code is working but can you explain how can i do it without show the form again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Show your frm2, you should call `frm2.Show();` or `frm2.ShowDialog();`.

Also, before 'Show' call you can set `frm2.TopMost = true;` if you want this form to be on the top.

So it could be:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.TopMost = true;
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: no i said that i'am already showed them but i want to focus on Form2 when i click on Form1

Answer (score 0):

If you already opened the form elsewhere, then this code will not work as it's a new instance of `Form2` and not the one that is opened.

You will have to keep a reference to the form that is opened, and then use `Focus` or might be better `Activate` on it.

if the form is opened from within `Form1` then:

1. Add a field for holding current reference of `Form2`
2. Save it when showing the form.
3. Use it when focusing

   ```
   private Form2 currentForm2;
   ....
   this.currentForm2 = new Form2();
   this.currentForm2.Show();
   ...
   ...
   this.currentForm2.Activate();
   ```